# Problem with session timeout in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, windows-2003-webserver

In my web.config file I tried `Session.Timeout="1"` and found working. Later I tried `Session.Timeout="20160"`. Even if I give such a large number my website "Session Transfers" are being expired in 15-20mins. Do I need to change any settings in IIS? I am using windows 2003 server.

Comment: Are you using Forms Authentication for your pages by any chance?

Comment: Not sure but I think yes. Its default IIS provided with windows 2003 server.

Comment: Is the website shutting down?  Session timeout won't stop your websites app domain being shut down by IIS if the website is inactive.  Try logging the Application_End event in Global.asax.  You can increase the idle timeout in the IIS configuration for the site.

Comment: I am sending a code from one page to another for authentication. This code is currently stored as session. When I reload page instantly there is no problem. If I reload page after 20 mins page is being redirected to login page. i.e. there is no more session code present over the page.

Comment: If it's exactly 20 mins then this is also the default idle timeout - so if your site is idle for that 20 mins then increase the idle timeout in the iis settings.

Comment: Try setting you session.Timeout to 1440. Your Session variables are no longer valid when referenced after 24 hours(1440). Which is why setting it to 20160 does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this :

http://forums.asp.net/t/1283350.aspx

Comment: I configured my server with these settings before a month but instead to change values for 20 to 14400 I disabled the check box and saved settings. Hope this will be optimized to the maximum time.

Answer (score 2):

define in the web configuration file:

```
<sessionstate 
      mode="inproc"
       cookieless="false" 
      timeout="20" 
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

define in here in web.config file:

```
 <system.web>
     <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms timeout="50" />
     </authentication>
 </system.web>
```

Comment: What about declaration in <sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="1440" />

Comment: In that case, I post a new question to know what is their difference?

Comment: cookieless sessions can easily be hijacked, so try and avoid. the following article outlines the problems. 
http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-3.html

Comment: @Nick - But its cookieless="false" na?

Comment: @kars, just wanted to point out its important to avoid cookieless sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like session timeout has a max of **24 hours**. Check this out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233477

Set it to 24 hours or less and you will be fine.

**Also explained here:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473(v=vs.90).aspx

> IIS 6.0: The minimum allowed value is
>   1 minute and the maximum is 1440
>   minutes.